# Operations upon the determinant of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

[what is the value of the determinant in the last question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSCOD.jpg)

I am having trouble finding the determinant in the last question.

I tried det = 15 because the first row is multiplied by 5, which multiples the original det value of 3 by 5. Then, I changed 15 into -15 because the rows are swapped.

I know that adding a scalar multiple of one row or column to another does not change the determinant. I assume if I factor out the negative sign from the last row so that it fits this rule. I end up with det = 15 again.

Where in my logic am I going awry?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Interchange the first and third row, this gives a $-1$. Now remove the $5$ from the third row, so you have a $5$ coming out, and the last two rows are $[d,e,f]$ and $[g,h,i]$, as with the usual matrix. Now, you must split the first row using linearity of the determinant (in its first row in our case):
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}
-3a-2d & -3b-2e & -3c - 2f \\
d&e&f \\
g&h&i 
\end{bmatrix}
 \\= 
\det\begin{bmatrix}
-3a & -3b & -3c \\
d&e&f \\
g&h&i 
\end{bmatrix}
+
\det\begin{bmatrix}
-2d & -2e &  - 2f \\
d&e&f \\
g&h&i 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The second matrix has determinant zero, and the first has determinant $-3 \times -3 = 9$.  Multiplying this with the $-1$ and $5$ we got earlier gives the result $-45$.

Comment: I think this answer could use a little clarification; it's not valid in general to compute the determinant of a sum of two matrices by summing the determinants. I'm assuming you're appealing to the multilinearity of the determinant?

Comment: Ah, then I would need a small edit.

Answer (score 0):

I would start from the third question. Multiplying the top row by $5$ produces a determinant of $15$. Then, multiplying the bottom row by $-3$ (the step you missed) makes a determinant of $-45$. Finally, subtract two lots of the second row from the third, which leaves the determinant at $-45$. As this produces the matrix in question, $-45$ is your answer.